# what does native="true" stand for in a Qt designer form

Tags: qt, qt4

I am doing a diff between 2 project versions and noticed that some of the ui files have extra attributes in the xml that I have not put there myself:

where would  native="true" come from? what would make it get added to the ui?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt GUIs can be displayed in many themes. `native="true"` forces the application to use the operating system's theme (on Linux, some QT apps look terrible because they don't look like the rest of the native apps).

Comment: thx.  What is odd is it has been applied to custom widgets only.

Comment: Huh. I've never had that happen, but it could be because I use Python with Qt4.

Comment: well both builds come from a different machine so I am going to investigate what triggered this.  Thanks for your answer.